# Mysql / Comments look / Vertically

Tags: php, html

I'v got a question. 
I have a mailform that also put the entered info in to db. 
I figuerd out how to print the db data to a table like this: 
( http://jobler.se/latest.php ) this table shows the 6 newest entrys from db.

But i want the table to look like this:
http://test3.fcab.se/blogtest/blogtest.php / Comment style.

Is it possible to show the db table vertically?

#### Code added from link:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM jobadd ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 6";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

?>
<table border="0" cellspacing=1" cellpadding="5" width="1230" higt="680px" table-cell; align="left">
<TH>Uppdragstyp</TH> <TH>Var</TH> <TH>Postnr</TH> <TH>Åt vem</TH> <TH>När</TH> <TH>ID Kod</TH> <TH>Beskrivning</TH></TR>

<col style="width: 140px" />
<col span="5" style="width: 130px" />
<col style="width: 350px" />

<?php
$i=0;

while ($i < $num){

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Vad");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Var");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"Postnr");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"Vem");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"När");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Idkod");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"Beskrivning");
?>

<tr>

<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>


</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some of your code. The answer is, yes of course, you can do what you want to. But we need to see your code to help you modify it.

Comment: You can find the code hear: http://test3.fcab.se/latest_php.txt (view sorce or F5 the page)

Comment: Your problem will be solved by looping over your results and producing the output in html, e.g. a div for each row. This is a not a Mysql question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to transpose rows into columns. The proper way to do this in MySQL is to use the GROUP_CONCAT function. Here is a good article explaining how [link](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can give you some idea how you can form it.

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM jobadd ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 6";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();


$i=0;
while ($i < $num) :
?>

    <div class="blogitem" style="display: block;">
    <div class="blogsubject"><a target="_parent" href="http://jobler.se/bygg.php"><?php echo mysql_result($result,$i,"Vad"); ?></a><br></div>
    <div class="blogdate">09/11/2011 21:33<br></div>
    <font face="Arial" color="#000000" style="font-size:13px"><br>
    <br>
    <?php echo mysql_result($result,$i,"Beskrivning"); ?>
    <br>
    </font><br>
    <div class="blogcomments"><a href="mailto:patrik@fcab.se?subject=Bygg &amp; Anläggning">Svara på denna ansökan</a></div>
    </div>
<?php
$i++;
endwhile;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I now have this code. But if u look att the link you will see that the mailform i added is not showing up on the top filed: codefile: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3182310/latest_php.txt   Page address: http://jobler.se/senaste6.php

Comment: Hi i wonder how i can get a price range from 0$ to 1500$ and then print out on a webpage that thr range 0$ to 1500$ = 100$

So if i have in the db table a column "price" and in that column there are differnt prices e.g 0-1500, 1500-3000, 3000-6000 etc.

Now i whant to print out on a webpage if the price in db is 0$-1500$ the resolt on page should be 100$, and if the price is 1500$-3000$ the print out is 200$

Can any boudy help me whit this pleas. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrikIdén I dont understand it. What is the relation between 0-1500 and 100, or 1500-3000 and 200? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: OK. igot a site whare a user can post a Job request. When the request is on the site, then a Company can answer on that request. Si if a user puts in 0-1500$ in the request yhen it shold cost 100$ for a Company to answer that request. So on the answering page there should be some code that gets the users price from the db and someware on the page puts out the price for answering 100$. Thank you for replying. /Patrik.